# Deeply nested object from array

Tags: javascript, recursion

How would you create a deeply nested object from an array. Like so...

```
const a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
```

to...

```
{
  a: {
    b: {
      c: {
        d: {}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and potentially as deep as there are elements in the array..

Comment: In short... `a.reduceRight((p, c) => ({ [c]: p }), {})`

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method.

```js
const a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

let res = {};

a.reduce((obj, e) => obj[e] = {}, res)

console.log(res)
```

---

Or with [`Array#reduceRight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight) method.

```js
const a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

let res = a.reduceRight((obj, e) => ({ [e]: obj }), {})

console.log(res)
```

Comment: How did you answer after I closed the question?

Comment: That's pretty cool returning the assignment in the first snippet :)